# Facebook Page - User Roles/Tasks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm creating a system which is integrated with Facebook login and depends on the roles a user has on a page ([Admin, Editor, Analyst, etc.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/#page-tasks))

Does it exists a Webhook field for the user page role update? (f.e: changing between admin, editor, etc.)

In case it doesn't, **what is the proper endpoint to get a user page role?**

I've found these endpoints:

`v3.1/<page_id>?fields=name,userpermissions{id,user,tasks}`

**Cons:**

- [userpermissions is deprecated on v3.2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.2/)
- can't filter by user_id (possibly needs to paginate to find out the permission for a specific user)

---

`v3.2/<page_id>/roles/<user_id>`

**Cons:**

- doesn't work on v3.3 but I couldn't find any official deprecation ("(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (roles) on node type (Page)"). The same request on v3.2 works.
- returns empty when using system user (business manager) page access token

---

`v3.3/<user_id>/accounts/`

**Cons:**

- can't filter by page_id (possibly needs to paginate to find out the permission for a specific page)